# Set navigation bar title to UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

here's some code that I am using to add UIBarButtonItems to my navigation bar, how can I change it display custom images, or images uploaded to my Xcode project?

```
UIBarButtonItem *shareItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:nil];

NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[shareItem, cameraItem];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *shareItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: shareItem, cameraItem, nil];
```

Also you can set not only your image, but also your custom UIView with this method:

```
- (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView
```

[See more info.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

`UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` is deprecated in iOS 8. Use `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` instead.

```
UIBarButtonItem *shareItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_clear"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[shareItem];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
```